# Ensure a suspend function call is completed even during cancellation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's assume we have some methods to insert into a database and modify stuff in it. The detail that matters here is that **they are suspend functions**.

```kotlin
interface Database {
  suspend fun insert(text: String): Long

  suspend fun markAsDone(id: Long)
}
```

Somewhere else in the code, we want to perform some activity which, if successful, must be reflected in the database. Let's oversimplify the implementation as well:

```kotlin
suspend fun doTheThing() {
    if (attempt(this.id)) db.markAsDone(this.id)
}
```

The problem I see here is that `doTheThing` suspends, hence it might be cancelled. If that happens, then `attempt` might turn out successful without the database knowing about it, because `markAsDone` could be cancelled reacting to `doTheThing`'s cancellation. In some cases this might lead to some problems (what if we exit our program, and after re-launching it the database tells it it hasn't been done yet, so the program does it again?)

How can we make sure the new state is written to the database?

One solution I can think of is launching a coroutine with a custom parent, but it looks a bit ugly:

```kotlin
suspend fun doTheThing() {
    if (attempt(this.id)) {
        launch(Job()) {
            db.markAsDone(this.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "because markAsDone could be cancelled reacting to doTheThing's cancellation" - Only if you make is so: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you can't launch a coroutine without a scope, and you're not waiting for it to finish, so the calling code can't treat this a proper synchronous suspend function.

Also, you probably want to to include the `attempt()` call inside the other coroutine. Otherwise, if it is fired and then the coroutine cancelled before it returns, your other coroutine to write to the database will never be called.

GlobalScope is appropriate for a coroutine that you don't want to be cancelled by some lifecycle event.

Putting all that together, you would have:

```
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
suspend fun doTheThing() = GlobalScope.launch {
    if (attempt(id)) {
        db.markAsDone(id)
    }
}.join()
```

---

Alternatively, you could prevent cancellation altogether, but the problem with this method is your calling coroutine cannot be promptly cancelled. If the coroutine is capturing references to things that are now out of scope (like obsolete UI elements), they will be leaked until the database write is complete.

One way to do this is with NonCancellable:

```
suspend fun doTheThing() = withContext(NonCancellable) {
    if (attempt(id)) {
        db.markAsDone(id)
    }
}
```

A second way to do it would be to design the implementations of both `attempt()` and `markAsDone()` to not cooperate with cancellation. This strategy would have to be done very carefully, If they call any of the suspend functions (directly or indirectly) from `kotlinx.coroutines`, which are all cancellable, they will in turn be cancellable. Really, there is hardly any reason to define a suspend function that doesn't call any other suspend function unless you're forced to make a function suspend due to an interface, so I don't think this is a realistic strategy.

Comment: "if it [`attempt`] is fired and then the coroutine cancelled before it returns, your other coroutine to write to the database will never be called." That's what I want, actually. If `attempt` is cancelled, then it shouldn't be considered as done.